# Add selected text wrapped in a tag inside a div

Tags: jquery

When clicking a list item, it appears in a the div with the 'schtuff' class 
I also want it to wrap each word inside a span (so I can style it or remove them with another click later).

I want to be creating a new span tag each time with the text I click inside it without altering the other span tags.
Script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.shtuff li').click(function(){
//var thistext= $(this).text();

$('.display').append("<span></span>");  

$('.display span').append($(this).text());  
    });

  });//ready
 </script>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
.display span{background-color:#ccc;}
.display{border:1px solid; width:300px;hieght:100px}
ul li {list-style-type:none;}

</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="display">some text</div>
<ul class="shtuff">
<li>blueberry </li>
<li>cherry </li>
<li>strawberry  </li>
<li>ferret droppings </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is it's appending to the other span tags as it does this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing

```
$('.display').append("<span></span>");
```

to

```
$('.display').append("<span>" + $(this).text() + "</span>");
```

Comment: @dystroy, @Vega$('.display span').click(function(){
//alert ("bu bye")
$(this).remove();
  }); isn't working to remove individual spans an ideas?

Comment: @namretiolnave You should post that as a new question.. but try this...`$('.display').on('click', 'span', function(){ //alert ("bu bye") $(this).remove(); });` - The span doesn't exist when that line was executed.

Comment: you were right it did work -I was using jquery 1.3 -any suggestions for developing for an older version?

Comment: @namretiolnave Try using `.live` which seems to be the only one available for v1.3. When you upgrade, try using the above syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Use this :

```
$('.shtuff li').click(function(){
   $('.display').append($("<span></span>").text($(this).text()));  
});
```